# How to show/hide buttons onFocus/onBlur below the textarea and allow to click it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I need to add two buttons below the input field.

One button will allow saving the input in the textarea, and another aborting.

The buttons should be displayed when the input is focused.

Currently, the problem is that when I click any of the buttons, the input gets blurred again and thus they disappear and the onClick event doesn't happen.

I use MUI and Formik.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```js
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

...

return (
...

<Box sx={inspectionWrapperStyles} mb={'0.25rem'}>
          <MultiLineInput
            name={fieldName}
            noMargin
            required={required}
            label={label}
            onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
            onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
            ref={inputRef}
          />
          {inputFocused && (
            <>
              <IconButton
                altText=""
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log('Saved');
                }}
              >
                <SaveIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                altText=""
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log('Aborted');
                }}
              >
                <XCircleIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          )}
        </Box>
        
...
)
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to set a timeout to your onBlur function ? See this great article explains how to do it correctly : https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks

Comment: it is not a good idea because a user should be able to click the button any time, even if they stay on the page for some time

Answer (score 0):

Looks like currently as you click a button the focus of the input is lost, so they disappear. Maybe it's a good idea to check if the button is clicked and only then hide it, like this:

```
{inputFocused && !buttonClicked (
```

then in both button's `onClick` you can add:

```
onClick={() => {
  console.log('Aborted');
  setButtonClicked(true);
}}
```

only thing left is to make sure that we reset it when input is focused again:

```
onFocus={() => {
  setInputFocused(true);
  setButtonClicked(false);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false); // add this

<MultiLineInput
         name={fieldName}
         noMargin
         required={required}
         label={label}
         onFocus={() =>{
          setInputFocused(true)
          setShowButton(true) // add this
           }}

         onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
         ref={inputRef}
       />
       {inputFocused && showButton && (
         <>
           <IconButton
             altText=""
             onClick={() => {
               console.log('Saved');
               setShowButton(false) // add this if you want to hide buttons
             }}
           >
             <SaveIcon />
           </IconButton>
           <IconButton
             altText=""
             onClick={() => {
              console.log('Aborted');
              setShowButton(false) // add this if you want to hide buttons
             }}
           >
             <XCircleIcon />
           </IconButton>
         </>
       )}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the focus gets lost and buttons dissapear